# Environment variable not found: DATABASE_URL. Prisma and mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, heroku, deployment, prisma

I've developped an API with Node.Js, Express, **Prisma** and **Mysql** in local firstly. After that it works, I have deployed my API on Heroku and I took the **ClearDB add-on to have a Mysql DB on Heroku**.

So the deployment is OKAY when I go on my root root URI I have the *"Cannot GET /"* message, and when I try to connect to my ClearDB with MysqlWorkbench I have my tables, columns etc...
The main problem is from Prisma.

When I go to the *"Run console"* of my Heroku's project, the command `npx prisma init` works perfectly BUT when I type `npx prisma migrate deploy || dev` or also if I try to `npx prisma db push` I have this error =>

> Error: Get Config: Schema parsing - Error while interacting with query-engine-node-api library
> Error code: P1012
> error: Environment variable not found: DATABASE_URL.
> -->  schema.prisma:10
> |
> 9 |   provider = "mysql"
> 10 |   url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
> |

All my code is in a GitHub repo, I've configured my `.env` (which is in the root folder of my server) like this :

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://<username>:<my-password>@eu-cdbr-west-30.cleardb.net/heroku_36d295ebb6686a2"
NODE_ENV="development"
APP_SECRET="jwtsecret12"
NODE_PATH="./src"

ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET="651651651848754cdfce9fz8ef4ef54se8f4sef48s69ef84e"
```

I hope you have all the informations that you need to help me :)

**PS : Locally my project works perfectly**

Waiting for your answers, thank you very much !

Comment: Please share your GitHub repo

Comment: Are you still having trouble with this?

Answer (score 0):

Your `.env` file is irrelevant. It should not be used on Heroku (and should not be tracked in your repository).

ClearDB provides an environment variable called `CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL`, not `DATABASE_URL`. You can either change your code to use this variable instead of `DATABASE_URL`, or you can [set `DATABASE_URL` to the same value](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cleardb#provisioning-the-shared-mysql-add-on):

> Retrieve your database URL by issuing the following command:
>
> ```
> heroku config | grep CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL
> CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL => mysql://adffdadf2341:adf4234@us-cdbr-east.cleardb.com/heroku_db?reconnect=true
> ```
>
> Copy the value of the `CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL` config variable.
>
> *If you’re using Ruby on Rails and the `mysql2` gem, you will need to change the `mysql://` scheme in the `CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL` to `mysql2://`*
>
> ```
> heroku config:set DATABASE_URL='mysql://adffdadf2341:adf4234@us-cdbr-east.cleardb.com/heroku_db?reconnect=true'
> Adding config vars:
> DATABASE_URL => mysql2://adffd...b?reconnect=true
> Restarting app... done, v61.
> ```

The connection information for Heroku Postgres can change at any time, but since the ClearDB documentation provides the preceding guidance I would hope that it does not do so.